# How to show alert only if all system and custom validation passes in salesforce?

Tags: visualforce, apex

I am working on the `Visualforce` and `Controller` in `salesforce`. When the Case save, that I time I need to show the alert, but this alert will only come into the picture if all my system validation and custom validation passes. How we can do this ? Any guidance?

I am using following code.

```
public Boolean save(){       
    try{                       
        Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
        if(currentCase.Id == null){     
            insert currentCase;
        }

        if(currentChildCase.Id == null){   
            try{
                currentChildCase.Case__c = currentCase.Id;
                if(currentChildCase.id == null){
                    insert currentChildCase; 
                }
            }
            catch(System.DmlException ex){
                System.debug('Exception for Transaction Rollback :: '+ex.getMessage());
                Database.rollback(sp);
                currentCase.Id = null;
                return false;
            }              
        } 
        return true;
    }
}
```

and on the VF Page I am using the below code

```
<apex:commandButton id="classicSave" onclick="callMySaveMethod()" reRender="msg" value="Save" />
<apex:actionFunction name="callSave" action="{!saveCase}" reRender="caseForm"/>

function callMySaveMethod() {
    var myMSG = $j("#test").attr("value");
    if(Object.keys(myMSG).length === 0 || myMSG == null){
        callSave();
    }else if(confirm(myMSG)){
        callSave();
    }   
}

<!-- This alert (if applicable) value is getting from backend on type & Sub-type selection-->
<input value="{!messageStr}" id = "test" type = "hidden" />
```

**How to only show alert if I know all validations are passes?** What changes do I need to make here ?

**Note: Once save() method called. No control is coming back to salesforce.**